# Make few fields of SharePoint list infopath form read only

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

My requirement is New form should have all fields editable and Edit form should have few fields read-only (Like ID entered by user in New form for the item).
How is it possible through form customization done using Infopath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a checkbox or any bool control that gets checked when a form is initially filled out and submitted to a SharePoint list, have it change value "on-submit". When the form loads just add a rule that if 'existingForm' (or whatever you name the control) is checked and if it is then disable/or hide the control.

You could disable the controls, or you could hide them completely and display their values through a calculated field/value which is normally hidden.